# Get substring after first digit occurrence in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, substring, trim

I am trying to extract the characters after(and include) the first digit:

```
ABC 123SD => 123SD
123 => 123
123SD => 123SD
ABC =>
```

My current solution is following,

```
var string1 = ABC 123SD;
var firstDigit = string1.match(/\d/);
var result = string1.slice($string.indexOf(firstDigit), 0);
```

Comment: How exactly did you try it?

Comment: And by the way, I think you missed some words in your question.

Comment: *Keep on doin'*

Comment: `s.replace(/^\D*/,'')`.

Answer (score 3):

Use a regular expression.

```js
var string = 'ABC 123SD';
var match = string.match(/\d.*/);
var result = match ? match[0] : '';
console.log(result);
```

`\d` matches the first digit, and `.*` matches everything after it.

Comment: This works like a charm. But it will throw an error when there is no digit in the string.

Comment: var result = string1.match(/\d.*/)?string1.match(/\d.*/)[0]:"";

Answer (score 1):

You can just remove all leading characters that aren't digits, e.g.

```js
function strip(s) {
  return s.replace(/^\D*/,'');
}

// Example
['ABC 123SD', '123', '123SD', 'ABC'].forEach(s => console.log(s + ' => ' + strip(s)));
```